# Correct way to insert another model entity inside _post_put_hook?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wonder if I could make a transactional insert operation inside the `_post_put_hook()`, or how should I deal with `put()` errors before any operation inside `_post_put_hook()`.

I'm using Google App Engine in Python. My code is something like this,

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
  ...
  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    Device.get_or_insert(self.device_id, device_name=self.device_name, ...)
  ...
```

Despite `get_or_insert()` is transactional I'm not sure if the new Device entity will have the correct data from Event's `put()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the Future argument passed to the hook is for. You can call it's `check_success()` method to ensure the `put()` operation succeeded.

```
class Event(ndb.Model):

  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    if not future or future.check_success() is None:
      Device.get_or_insert(self.device_id, device_name=self.device_name, ...)
```

You can read more about the Future class in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/futureclass).

Comment: it was trivial, i should pay more attention to the docs, thanks!